# Android: how to make a ListView that looks similar to Preferences?

Tags: android

I do not want to use the framework provided Preferences, rather I would like to create a ListView that looks similar.  In particular, I would like it to use the same font size and style for the TextViews.

Comment: That will totally depend on what framework are you talking about. Each vendor has specific tweaks to differentiate it from the others. You can always grab the Settings.apk from your fw, decompile it with apk manager and dive into the xmls there to get an idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not about the ListView itself, but rather the child views that appear inside the ListView. They are created by the getView method of your adapter.

To create views similar to Android, you can use the Android source code, specifically the relevant XML file layouts. For example, preference.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:maxLines="4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You will not be able to use this content directly, as some of the constants used are private to Android, and you'll have to further dig down through other xml's.

Anyhow, you should take into account that Android preferences look different on different versions of Android, and on different themes, so make sure you use the constants provided by Android, and not your own hard-coded values, to make sure your list-view items resemble the actual preferences provided by Android.

Comment: Where are this file (preference.xml) and related preference layout files located in the Android source code? Edit: I answer myself, better search in the SDK folder: `\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\layout` (files starting with "preference".

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to the activity tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Preference.PreferenceScreen"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html